# setBackgroundResource() to spinner in Android 5 not works

Tags: android, spinner

strange things happen. I am trying to set background to spinner. `spinner.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.spinner_error);` This code works perfect in lower Android versions than 5, but in lollipop, this code do nothing. I tried to change color `spinner.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);` but it only makes spinner invisible. So, how to change spinner color/resource ?

EDIT:
Adapter code:

```
public class FuelStoragesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ModelFuelStorage> {

    private Context context;
    private List<ModelFuelStorage> fuelStorages;
    private boolean addAdditionalItems = false;

    public FuelStoragesAdapter(Context context, List<ModelFuelStorage> fuelStorages, boolean addAdditionalItems) {
         super(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, fuelStorages);
        this.context = context;
        this.fuelStorages = fuelStorages;
        this.addAdditionalItems = addAdditionalItems;
        setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_layout);
        if (addAdditionalItems)
            addAdditionalItems();
    }

    public void addStorage(ModelFuelStorage fuelStorage) {
        insert(fuelStorage, getCount() - 1);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void addAdditionalItems() {
         fuelStorages.add(new ModelFuelStorage(0, context.getString(R.string.add_new_storage), 0));
         fuelStorages.add(new ModelFuelStorage(-1, context.getString(R.string.choose_storage), 0));
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        if (addAdditionalItems)
            return super.getCount() - 1; // you dont display last item. It is used as hint.
        else
            return super.getCount();
    }

    public int getPosition(int storageId){
        for(ModelFuelStorage storage : fuelStorages)
            if(storage.getId() == storageId)
                return  fuelStorages.indexOf(storage);
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: you are setting "R.layout.spinner_dropdown_layout" layout to your spinner. Share the code of this please.

Answer (score 2):

Give try to this code:

```
spinner.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFF00"));
```

"#FFFF00" instead of this use any other color code.This is working for me in Android v5.

Comment: I am getting same result as with `spinner.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);` - spinner becomes invisible.

Comment: @Eddwhis I've tried this code on android 5.0.1 and it worked. just change the #FFFF00 to #FFFF0000 to get the red color

Comment: I don't know what to show. I have simple spinner `<Spinner
            android:id="@+id/fuel_storage"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>`  , initializing it and just setting color. I can you whatever code I want but result the same. And now noticied what result is the same and in lower Android versions.

Comment: show your items and your `ArrayAdapter` , if you don't set any adapter, your spinner doesn't contain any items, so it won't show anything

Comment: Don't know why it is not working in your case, but in my app, I'm checking for android v 5.1.1 and it's working fine. Just try once from other color codes.

Comment: I've given an answer below, just in case you need some help with setting up the adapter

Comment: Added ArrayAdapter code to question. I tried a lot of different colors. And I noticed that  the same thing happens with spinner and in lower Android versions if I want to change color with `setBackgroundColor` method.  `setBackgroundResource` works in pre lollipop devices, but do nothing in lollipop .

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this is to add this code when creating the spinner dynamically:

```
spinner.setPopupBackgroundResource(R.drawable.spinner);
```

and to create spinner.xml under Drawable folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="#ffffff" />
</shape>
```

This solution require API level of 16 and above.

Comment: Sorry, but I need solution which will works on API 9 too.

Comment: It changes spinner popup background , but not spinner background.

Comment: Try with Simple Background method as setBackgroundResource() and if it is working then make a condition with api level as if level greater than 16 then apply like this otherwise your other code which works in less than Android 5.

Comment: But nor `setPopupBackgroundResource` , nor `setBackgroundResource` changes spinner background. I need to change spinner background, not its popup background.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Lollipop Version you have to implement code for kitkat version and lollipop  version separately , please do this code for change background of spinner. its example of image background changes of images.

```
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT => Build.VERSION_CODES.KitKat) 
                        {
                            //for Lollipop Vession

//set color in this block which you want 
spinner.setBackgroundDrawable(Color.RED);
                        }
                        else
                        {
    // for Kikat Version

spinner.setBackgroundResource(xyz);
//set color in this block which you want 
                        }
```

i hope it helps you, if it is useful code for then please mark me .. Thanx.. :)

Comment: Spinner doesn't have method `getDrawable`.

Comment: @Eddwhis :- i am edited code , please check it, is it help you?

Answer (score 0):

Have you set any adapter to your spinner? if not use something like this:
Place in your activity's `onCreate()` method:

```
//Get your spinner
spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);

// Defined Array values to show in ListView
String[] values = new String[] { "item1",
            "item2",
            "item3"};

//Construct the ArrayAdapter
ArrayAdapter<String> spinneradapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, android.R.id.text1, values);

 //Set the adapter to the corresponding spinner
spinner.setAdapter(spinneradapter);

 //Change background color to "RED"
 spinner.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFF0000"));
```

**Tested, Works with android 5.0.1**

Hope this will help you out